# How to prevent cache in WebApp, Flutter for Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

We have a Flutter WebApp and, in every deployment the user has to delete the cache, so, the task is to prevent the cache, so every deployment has to work letting the final user with no unnecesary steps before starting to work...

`i have tried adding the line:` entrypointUrl: "main.dart.js?v=" + serviceWorkerVersion`

but when i do that, in the deployment i got the error:
`Exception while loading service worker: Error: Service worker not supported (or configured). at FlutterServiceWorkerLoader.loadServiceWorker (flutter.js:122:11) at FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint (flutter.js:358:33) at VM26 login-one:4:23 Unexpected token '<' in the main.dart.js?v=(serviceWorker_Number)`

Making the page get stuck charging the home page.
here is the html code:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="admin_dashboard">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="SU-VAN-Vertical.png" />

  <title>Su-Van</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_serialString_iJustChangeIt_for_default_text"></script>

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="loading_indicator" class="container" style="height: 100vh;; display:flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
    <img class="indicator" src="./assets/Ripple.gif" />

  </div>

  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        **entrypointUrl: "main.dart.js?v=" + serviceWorkerVersion,**
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        }
      }).then(function (engineInitializer) {
        return engineInitializer.initializeEngine();
      }).then(function (appRunner) {
        return appRunner.runApp();
      });
    });

  </script>
</body>

</html>`
```

I reached the hompage Starts normally after commenting the "entryPointUrl" line but still got the error:
`Exception while loading service worker: Error: Service worker not supported (or configured). at FlutterServiceWorkerLoader.loadServiceWorker (flutter.js:122:11) at FlutterLoader.loadEntrypoint (flutter.js:358:33) at VM26 login-one:4:23`

By the way, this isn't a solution because browsers keeps charging cache, anyone knows how could i shoot this errors and then, complete the task, that is making the browsers to download the new main.dart file if there is a new version of the app?

`• Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git • Framework revision f468f3366c (7 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700 • Engine revision  • Dart version 3.0.6 • DevTools version 2.23.1`